# Trying to update the title a UIButton in response to being selected

Tags: ios, ios7, uibutton

I am trying to update the title from u -> d on a button when it is selected. The setting to 'u' works fine but afer I click the button, it doens't update.  I am putting it into the action but not sure if this is correct place.

in viewDidLoad

```
[self.expandButton setTitle:@"u" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

where do I put this? - not working correctly in the UIButton's action:

```
[self.expandButton setTitle:@"d" forState: UIControlStateSelected];
```

thx for any help

### edit 1

Is set as a property:
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *expandButton;

...

here's the action and how I am trying to set the selected state:

```
- (IBAction)expand:(id)sender {
    [self.expandButton setTitle:@"d" forState: UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: you want to change the title when button selected or when highlighted ?

Comment: Where is the code for setting the "d" title?

Comment: I want to update the UIButton from u -> d when the user has clicked the button. Do I need to set anything else up?

Answer (score 0):

...

## EDITED

what I got is, when the button tapped, the state change to *selected*, and when tapped again state back to *normal*. you can use these trick :

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    
    [button setTitle:@"unselected" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitle:@"selected" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)buttonTap:(UIButton *)sender {
    sender.selected = !sender.selected;
}
```

Comment: thx - I might not be getting UIButton - this basically flashes to black and then goes back to u. hmm.... Do I need to set the button to the 'selected' state somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function to set button title and call it on touch down:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouchDown:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a "blank" button and use a UILabel on top of it.  I'm not sure of why you aren't getting updates but in my experience I usually deal with this situation in such a way.